# Inserting Large Amounts of Edges into OrientDB causes crash (ODatabaseException)

Tags: database, insert, bulkinsert, orientdb

I'm having problems inserting a large amount (few million) of edges in OrientDB. In java, I have a matrix with ~5000 rows and columns where each entry represents the similarity value between the objects. I want to insert this information into OrientDB.

But after creating between 200k and 400k edges, a ODatabaseException happens and I haven't found a solution to this problem.

I'm creating the edges in the following way: Using [SQL Batch](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-batch.html), I add the SQL query to a string and execute the batch for each 100 edges. Each SQL line looks like this:

```
CEATE EDGE similarity FROM #10:0 TO #10:1 SET score = 0.5
```

Should I be doing this in a different way? Is it a lack of memory problem? I haven't been able to find a solution for this.

Thanks.

**Edit:**

I'm updating the question with the exception and a bit of the code:

**The code:**

```
public void saveHouseCharacteristicsSimilarities(double[][] houseSim,
        ArrayList<OHouse> houseList) {

    OrientGraphFactory factory = new OrientGraphFactory("plocal:/directory");
    OrientGraphNoTx graph = factory.getNoTx();

    int counter=0;
    String query = "BEGIN\n";
    for (int h1 = 0; h1 < (houseList.size() - 1); h1++) {
        for (int h2 = (h1 + 1); h2 < houseList.size(); h2++) {
            counter++;

            query += "create edge similarity from "
                    + houseList.get(h1).getRid() + " to "
                    + houseList.get(h2).getRid() + " SET score = "
                    + houseSim[h1][h2] + "\n";

            if (counter % 100 == 0
                    || ((h1 == (houseList.size() - 1)) && (h2 == (houseList
                            .size() - 1)))) {
                query += "COMMIT";
                graph.command(new OCommandScript("sql", query)).execute();
                query = "BEGIN";
            }
        }
    }
    graph.shutdown();
}
```

**And the exception** (at this specific point I had already saved 250000 edges):

```
  com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ODatabaseException: Error on retrieving record #24:1880 (cluster: house)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.executeReadRecord(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:1605)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.tx.OTransactionOptimistic.loadRecord(OTransactionOptimistic.java:226)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.load(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:1424)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.load(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:117)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.id.ORecordId.getRecord(ORecordId.java:313)
    at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientBaseGraph.getVertex(OrientBaseGraph.java:731)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.graph.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLCreateEdge$1.call(OCommandExecutorSQLCreateEdge.java:144)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.graph.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLCreateEdge$1.call(OCommandExecutorSQLCreateEdge.java:126)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.graph.sql.OGraphCommandExecutorSQLFactory.runInTx(OGraphCommandExecutorSQLFactory.java:123)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.graph.sql.OGraphCommandExecutorSQLFactory.runInTx(OGraphCommandExecutorSQLFactory.java:141)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.graph.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLCreateEdge.execute(OCommandExecutorSQLCreateEdge.java:126)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.execute(OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.java:64)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.executeCommand(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:1184)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.command(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:1173)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.OCommandRequestTextAbstract.execute(OCommandRequestTextAbstract.java:63)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.script.OCommandExecutorScript.executeSQLScript(OCommandExecutorScript.java:335)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.script.OCommandExecutorScript.executeSQL(OCommandExecutorScript.java:138)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.script.OCommandExecutorScript.executeInContext(OCommandExecutorScript.java:82)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.script.OCommandExecutorScript.execute(OCommandExecutorScript.java:73)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.executeCommand(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:1184)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.command(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:1173)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.OCommandRequestTextAbstract.execute(OCommandRequestTextAbstract.java:63)
    at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientGraphCommand.execute(OrientGraphCommand.java:48)
    at com.ubiwhere.livinx.recEngine.dao.OHouseDAO.saveHouseCharacteristicsSimilarities(OHouseDAO.java:465)
    at com.ubiwhere.livinx.recEngine.structures.CharacteristicsSimilarity.buildCharacteristicsMatrix(CharacteristicsSimilarity.java:33)
    at com.ubiwhere.livinx.rest.house.HouseFavouriteService.getFavourites(HouseFavouriteService.java:195)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:171)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:152)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:387)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:331)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:254)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1028)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:372)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(Proc
```

Comment: Can you post some code and also the exception?

Comment: I updated the question with the info you asked

Comment: Why don't you use java api instead of sql for creating edges?

Comment: I've always preferred using SQL and, unless the java API has better performance, I see no reason to use it. But that's just personal preference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, seems like the problem wasn't with Orient itself, but the glassfish server where the program was running. Glassfish terminated the connection with Orient for some reason. Anyways, running the program outside the server solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try something like this for creating edges

```
OrientVertex vertex = graph.getVertex(houseList.get(h1).getRid());
OrientVertex vertex2 = graph.getVertex(houseList.get(h2).getRid());
vertex.addEdge("similarity",vertex2,new Object[]{"score",houseSim[h1][h2]});
```

Comment: Gives pretty much the same results and performance wise is pretty much the same as using SQL.

Comment: Do you get the exception with java instead of SQL?